# What is Proper Attribution for Non-code Resources (Academic papers, etc) in OSS?

Tags: mit, derivative-works, attribution

What is considered the proper way to attribute or acknowledge non-code non-software resources from which part of a piece of software could be considered to be derived (when intending to release the software under a relatively permissive license such as the MIT/Expat license)?

The specific example which I am considering is the issue of a Python script, the code of which utilizes (non-code) definitions and formulae from non-software-related academic papers. Plenty of resources make it clear how to properly attribute the papers in (for example) another academic paper, but it is a little less clear how to appropriately attribute non-code resources in a software work. The script itself is not part of an academic work of its own (so academic attribution can't simply be deferred to said work, since there is none). In such a context, how should the attribution be performed (or can the script be released at all)?

Comment: You can always give attribution in a comment. Certain formulas may not be copyrightable however, in which case they would not strictly be relevant to licensing. This is a difference between the idea of copyright and the idea of authorship (and plagiarism etc.)